# Scroll Fade up and appears. wont function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I have been working with this piece of code for a while and its finally got the best of me I have input all my code into the JSfiddle and the code work on it but when i transfer the code to my website it doesn't work. The jsfiddle with all my code is here .[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4FM9/1739/). This is the code I am working on on my host webpage.

The html of the section I want to fade in and out on scroll.
My code :

```js
var divs = $('.fade');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
    divs.stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
  } else {
    divs.stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="hero" class="fade" class="container">

  <h2> Welcome. Lets take a journey into the sea </h2>

</div>
```

I don't know whether I should put the JS code on a separate JS file or straight on the page with the html

any help that could be offered would be appreciated

thank you

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be defining the class attribute twice on your div. It should be class="fade container"

Comment: If it works in one environment and not a different one I'd look at differences in the environments. Have you checked that you have jQuery loaded correctly on your host page? If you use Firebug to step through the code where is it failing and what are the messages?